# Make black pixels transparent in GeoTIFF using Python

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal2tiles

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to convert the following black pixels or null data to transparent so when I turn it into tiles I can't see them.

[image: GeotiffImage]

I'm trying to do it in Python so I can automate it. Is there a tool I can use that can handle this?

Comment: THis appears to be a repost? [Convert BEAM-DIMAP data to GeoJSON data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/433347/convert-beam-dimap-data-to-geojson-data)

Comment: Yeah in that one I was trying to convert it to a geojson but I managed to work around that for what I need. im now trying to make the black pixels transparent on the tif file so when I display the data as tiles It doesnt display it on the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gdal.Warp to make a new file with black as nodata using WarpOptions with kwargs.  Here is an example using Python and gdal on Windows.  The WarpOptions may be slightly different that the command line version of gdalwarp.  [See here](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions) for the correct options.

Maybe you have a single band image and would only need a single 0?

```
from osgeo import gdal
infile = r"C:\foo.tif"
outfile = r"C:\bar.tif"
kwargs ={'dstNodata' :"0, 0, 0"}
ds = gdal.Warp(outfile, infile, **kwargs )
del ds
```